# javascript facebook application force user to allow application to access his data

Tags: javascript

the question purpose is not for hacking purpose, iam doing an application that renders facebook itself, so once the user buy my application it means he permitted my application to access his data.
so i need to click on facebook allow application access data button programmatically.

is there a way to do so by javascript or any language?

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook don't want you doing this.  If you find a way to do it, you should expect Facebook will find a way to stop you.  I suggest re-thinking your approach.

Comment: I can't see an ethical reason for doing this, and I would suggest you describe in more detail exactly what you are trying to do if you need more help.  You can use the edit link below your question to do this.